# How to add private methods inside the prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, static-methods

If possible, how do I add private methods inside the prototype?

In the code below, the instance `item1` contains `#calcTax()` in the instance itself but not inside the prototype. Is there any way to add `#calcTax()` inside the prototype?

```js
class CartItem {
  #dateAdded = Date.now();
  tax;

  constructor(id, name, qty, price) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.qty = qty;
    this.price = price;
    this.totalPrice = qty * price;
    this.#calcTax();
  }

  #calcTax() {
    this.tax = this.totalPrice * 0.13;
  }
}

const item1 = new CartItem(52, 'Burger', 2, 9.99);
console.log(item1);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @Unmitigated to me having methods in the instances seems like inefficient. Isn't it better to delegate methods to constructor (or in other words inherit from constructor)? What if the private method contains some huge lines of code? Does every instance created from the class now have that private method attached to it? I am trying to get the answers to these questions and if there is any way to put private methods inside the prototype, what is it?

Comment: So are you asking something like: "Does having private class features make the object use more memory than the equivalent syntax that does not make use of private class features?"  (I would suggest a side-by-side A/B comparison of example code, if that's your question.)

Comment: I do not believe private methods are moved to the instance just because they are private?